# Problem defining a fancyvrb verbatim environment within tcolorbox

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, fancyvrb

I want to define an environment for verbatim text using fancyvrb functionality, but within an entitled frame drawn using tcolorbox. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{box1}
{\Verbatim[numbers=left,numbersep=2em,commandchars=\\\{\}]}%
{\endVerbatim}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{box1}{%
\tcolorbox[title={Box title}]}

\AfterEndEnvironment{box1}{%
\endtcolorbox}

\newenvironment{box2}[1]
{\tcolorbox[title={#1}]
\Verbatim[numbers=left,numbersep=2em,commandchars=\\\{\}]}%
{\endVerbatim
\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{box1}
Some \textcolor{red}{text}
\end{box1}

\clearpage
\begin{box2}{Box2 title}
Some other \textcolor{red}{text}
\end{box2}

\end{document}
```

Now, the definition of `box1` which uses hooks `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` works as expected.

However, I want my environment to accept the title given as parameter, as in definition of `box2`. I believe I can't pass parameters to the hooks, so the tcolorbox has to be part of the newenvironment definition. However, I am not able to make it work. The use of `box2` gives me:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.30 \end{box2}
```

Any hint to make it working?

Comment: How can you expect it to work without passing the parameter. The definition of box2 is correct. What are you expecting with the behavior of box1.

Comment: I do pass a parameter to `box2` environment, namely `{Box2 title}`. And `box2` does not work, I cited the error. `box1` served as an example which works, but using environment hooks which do not allow for parameters so it has a constant title. The problem is that I do not understand why the definition of `box1` works while that of `box2` does not, as they both do seemingly identical things (apart from the parameter in the second one).